# how to move element back to origin after animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, position

Im kinda new to html and css, so I was doing youtube clone website and  I am having this problem with navigation. In official website when you click on hamburger it will close the navigation and shows smaller version of it while main content area shifts left taking nav space. My problem is when I open  navigation back main content area is not moving back to origin causing side navigation overlaping the main content.

Comment: Hello)) Without html, css and js code (if any) you can only be given superficial answers or far-reaching suggestions. Add the problematic and reproducible part of the project, and we will try to help you.

Comment: i just wanna do youtube.com hamburger toggle

Answer (score 0):

This is how, you can toggle side navigation.

```js
var isOpen = false;
function toggleSideMenu() {
isOpen = !isOpen;
if(isOpen) {
  document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "200px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "200px";
} else {
  document.getElementById("sideMenu").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
}
```

```css
body {
font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
}
.side-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #001f8e;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.side-menu a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #b1c2ff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.side-menu a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

#main h2 {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sideMenu" class="side-menu">
  <a href="#">Page 1</a>
  <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  <a href="#">Page 3</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2 onclick="toggleSideMenu()">&#9776; Menu</h2>
</div>
```